# Git - Pull/Push com diferentes repositórios

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitlab

Possuo um projeto que faz o envio para 2 repositórios ao mesmo tempo utilizando o mesmo remote, exemplo:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = https://gitlab.com/teste.git
url = http://bitbucket.org/teste.git
```

Nesse tipo de situação, quando eu quiser puxar o projeto, ele vai utilizar qual dos 2 links como base ?

Teria alguma maneira de definir qual link eu quero utilizar na hora de puxar ?

Creio que ele não puxe dos 2 repositórios ao mesmo tempo, pois caso houvesse diferença entre eles seria apontado algum erro ou algo do tipo.

Comment: as duas branchs possuem o mesmo nome? poque você pode especificar o nome dessa forma: git push origin [nome-branch]

Comment: Sim, com o mesmo nome, porém minha duvida é na hora do pull, de qual das URLs o Git irá puxar.

Comment: Se não me engano, se vc rodar `git remote -v`, ele mostra uma das URLs como *fetch* - é dessa que ele fará o *pull*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com esse cenário você terá problema, já que os repositórios que estão na origem podem ter commits diferentes.

Uma configuração que poderia ser tentada seria ter 3 origins, ou melhor 3 remotes, um com as duas URL's e outros 2 remotes, cada um configurado com 1 URL's. Desta forma você poderia enviar para 2 repositórios, mas para receber poderia usar primeiro um remote e depois o outro, tornando o seu repositório o centralizador do merge.

Manter um cenário dessa maneira é desnecessário se o objetivo for backup. As duas URL's usadas como exemplo, pelo menos, contam com ótimos serviços de backup.
Já se a ideia for ter redundância de serviços para caso de falha, existem outras maneiras de sincronizar os repos, que seria a solução mais simples, mas foge ao escopo dessa pergunta.